# Lebesgue Integrability of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}$ on $ [0, \infty)$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I am currently studying Lebesgue integrability and encountered the following problem:

For which values of $a$ is the following integral Lebesgue integrable:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}dx.$$

Of course this is equivalent to showing that the absolute value of the integrand converges.

Here's my approach and I would like to know if it is correct.

1.) $a\leq 0$:

For $a\leq 0$ one can estimate the integral in the following (standard) way
$$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x^a}dx>\frac{1}{((k+1)\pi)^a}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}|\sin(x)|dx=\frac{2}{((k+1)\pi)^a}.$$
Summing this over values of 0 to $\infty$ for $a\leq 0$ will diverge. Hence, for a\leq 0 not Lebesgue integrable.

2.) $a>0$
First I split the integral into two parts:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x^a}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x^a}dx=:I_1+I_\infty.$$

Consider first $I_1$.

This integral can be estimated in the following way: As $$\frac{Sin(x)}{x}\rightarrow 1$$ for $$x\rightarrow 0$$ the integrand effectively goes like $1/x^{a-1}$ and this is only convergent on [0,1] if $1<a<2$ (which can again be shown be standard means), otherwise it will blow up and the integral not Lebesgue integrable.

Thus it remains to show that $I_\infty$ is convergent for the range $1<a<2$ but this is obvious, as
$$I_\infty\leq \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^a}dx<\infty$$

---

Finally: I have shown that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}dx$$
is Lebesgue integrable for $1<a<2$.

**Is my reasoning correct and mathematically bulletproof?**

Comment: First, you say it is not Lebesgue integrable for $a\geq 0$ (but your argument is wrong), and then you conclude it is Lebesgue integrable for $1<a<2$. Go through the first argument again. Is the sum you mentioned in 1) really divergent for all $a\geq 0$?

Comment: @mickep: Ah sorry, I messed the ranges for a up. See above for the correct values of a.